# form without a submit button is still submitted?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form below with a button, but the button is not a submit one. Why the form is still submitted when clicking the button?

```
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input is-large" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">
    Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most browsers the `default type` of button is `submit` . This attribute declares the type of the button.if you add type attribute like this <button `type="button"`> then submit not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `type` attribute as `button` then the button won't submit the form. Ex:

```
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp